Existence of transitive set of a homeomorphism
Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space without isolated points and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism such that the $\mathbb{Z}$-action on $X$ that is defined by $f$ is minimal. Namely, for each $x\in X$, the orbit of $x$ defined below:
$$
[x]_f = \big\{ f^n(x): n\in \mathbb{Z} \big\}
$$
is dense in $X$. For each subset $A\subseteq X$, we define the orbit of $A$ the same way:
$$
[A]_f = \big\{ f^n(a): a\in A,\, n\in\mathbb{Z} \big\}
$$
In this case, is it always true that, or is there a necessary condition that implies that there exists a proper subset $A\subseteq X$ such that $[A]_f=X$?
This is a rather naive example. In a compact metric space $(X, d)$, suppose there exists $r>1$ such that for any $x, y\in X$, $d\big( f(x), f(y) \big) \geq rd(x, y)$, or we call $f$ is $r$-expansive. Then clearly for any (proper) open ball $B$, the diameter of $f^n(B)$ will increase as $n$ increases, and hence $[B]_f$ must be the entire $X$ since the diameter of $X$ is finite in this case. However, in this example, I am considering a compact metric space $(X, d)$ that has an $r$-expansive homeomorphism, but in general do not know if any compact metric space can have an $r$-expansive homeomorphism.
Counter-examples of a compact metric space that does not have any $r$-expansive (or even $1$-expansive) homeomorhpism, and counter-examples to my question above are both welcomed.
Updates: This post shows that in the set-up above an $f$-invariant subset always exists even when $f$ is not invertible.

There are no expansive compact metric spaces (consisting of more than one point). You can always take your $A$ to be the complement to a singleton.

By "expansive" compact metric space, do you mean the one that has an expansive homeomorphism? If without details, it is not clear to me that $\big[ X\backslash {x} \big]_f$ is always equal to $X$. Please see the link I included in the post, which shows that there is always an $f$-invariant closed subset of $X$. In particular, such an $f$-invariant closed subset could be a fixed point of $f$ when $f$ is contractive.

If $f$ is not the identity take any orbit of $f$ containing at least two different points $x,y$ with $fx=y$. Then $A=X\setminus{y}$ is a proper subspace of $X$ with $[A]_f=X$.

Your are right. I just forgot how I define the orbit. Perhaps in the next question I can look for a subset of $X\backslash {y}$ that has more properties.
